# Minecraft (i cant register)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I cannot seem to register a Minecraft account because for some reason the register button is greyed out.

[image: Registration for with grayed out button]

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score -1):

It may be a glitch.

Have you restarted the device, Checked the data for the game, or is the game corrupted. It also could be a demo